# API test automation using singleton HTTPClient and parallel test execution

Tags: java, web-services, automation, automated-tests, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to automate the APIs in my project using HTTPClient and I am planning to make use of a singleton Client which can be shared by various requests. So, here is the code for my singleton class:

```
public class Login {
    private static Login Login = null;
    private static HttpClient client = null;

    public static Login singletonClient() throws IOException {
        if (Login == null) {
            Login = new Login();

            client = new HttpClient();

            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";
            String server = "http://www.myserver.com";
            Integer port = "8080";

            Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
            client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(server, port), defaultcreds);
            client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
        }
        return Login;
    }

    public HttpClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

The way this will be used in my tests is:

```
HttpClient client = Login.singletonClient().getClient();
```

Considering that I have to automate 10 different API in my project and the username, password remains same for all the APIs, I have following questions w.r.t this Implementation:

1. I will be running my tests in parallel (say I have separate class for each API and all the classes need to be run in parallel). Can I run my tests in parallel using Singleton HTTP Client or Static HTTP client?
2. If I cannot run my tests in parallel, Is it good to get rid of singleton client or static client?

Please note that I am a novice in Java and please excuse if I am missing/confusing things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your intention of making your HttpClient a singleton? Why not create a builder that creates new instances of you client for each of your APIs?

Comment: Hi, While referring some documents online, I read that "Do NOT recreate HTTPClient for each request. Reuse Httpclient as much as possible". So, I was thinking to make it singleton. But it wasn't mentioned if this holds good for parallel/concurrent requests. As per my understanding, I can have a separate HTTPClient for each class. But can that be done even with Singleton class?